# How to create a custom frontpage using page--front.tpl.php and keep theme responsiveness

Tags: theming

I want my frontpage to be displayed with a full width image, some H2 header text and a navigation menu.

However using a page--front.tpl.php and applying custom css i am losing the natural responsiveness of my theme (at-subtheme), leaving me to apply mediaqueries.

What would be the apporiate way to set up a custom front page using my theme responsiveness?

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to set up a frontpage in drupal. I think the 2 most used ways are [panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels) or [context](https://www.drupal.org/project/context).

Panels allows you to create a page through drag and drop functinality. Almost every piece of content created in drupal (nodes, views, blocks, custom blocks, ...) can be added to a panel. In addition to that, if you use for example "omega" as a base theme, omega has a couple of default (responsive) build in templates you can use with the panels module.

Context allows you to expose content through conditions. So you can expose a block, view, node,... only on your frontpage. You will have to apply css to make your frontpage responsive though...

Both modules have there advantages and disadvantages, you should check them out and decide which is best for you. I'm certain there are other ways to create a frontpage, but this is how I usually get the job done.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried panels in combination with at_subtheme. Inserting an image (with image field)in a node and node in a panel node left me with 100%width but still a scrollbar. On the top i had margin left of 10px. I was able only able to get a proper widht and height to insert the image with css in the node, resulting in losing the theme responsiveness....

Comment: You can't expect your theme to do everything for you, sometimes you just have to write your own css to make your theme perfectly responsive...